# How do I bulk delete all content posted prior a chosen date?

Tags: nodes, views

How can I bulk delete all content posted prior a chosen date? Let's say I want to delete every node posted before/up to year 2012, but keep the ones after 2012.

How can I achieve it in Drupal 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Views Bulk Operations (VBO)](https://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module, you can:

1. Create a VBO view
2. Add a filter (could expose it) for content "Post date" less then required date
3. Add a bulk operation to "Delete item"
4. Save the view

With the view you just created, you can then bulk delete the selected nodes.